# Outputting empty lines between grep results when running it with -C (or -B / -A)

Tags: linux, bash, grep

Consider the following grep command over this toy input:

```
user@user:~$ echo -e "a\nb\nc\nd\ne" | egrep "(b|d)" -C 1 -n
1-a
2:b
3-c
4:d
5-e
```

Although this is quite good already as it is, I was wondering if there was some kind of trick to get an empty line between different results. Something akin to:

```
user@user:~$ echo -e "a\nb\nc\nd\ne" | egrep "(b|d)" -C 1 -n
1-a
2:b
3-c

3-c
4:d
5-e
```

Is there?

Thanks

Comment: Odd; according to the man page, there should be a `--` (default value of `--group-separator`) separating the two groups. (I am using `grep` 2.20.)

Comment: @chepner: Only if the groups don't overlap.

Comment: Ah, indeed. I'm not sure that's worded well in the documentation.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know about that --group-separator. That seems exactly what I was looking for. Anyone care to answer to this post so I can close this question?

Comment: @choroba: Interestingly enough `egrep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD` outputs the separator with overlapping groups.

Comment: @l'L'l but where does it put the separator if the groups overlap by, say, 3 lines? At the start of the overlap or at the end or just arbitrarily close to the middle? If they're just contiguous there's an obvious place to put a separator but not if they overlap. With other greps it looks like it's not only that the groups can't overlap, but they can't even be contiguous (which IMHO makes perfect sense). devouredelysium wrt your comment `That seems exactly what I was looking for.` - there's no answer to your question here as far as I can see.

Comment: @EdMorton: It stacks the separators, and I from what I can tell if the overlap is greater than a certain size it shows just one. Here's the output: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/47367296e1950f5278060034181b0998

Comment: @l'L'l that is so bizarre! It's got to be a bug, I think, as I can't see any use for it or imagine the rationale behind it. Thanks for posting.

Comment: It's interesting no doubt. Using`-C 3` on upwards the separator is in the same place every time as `-C 2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't do that with grep. You can do it with awk though:

```
$ echo -e "a\nb\nc\nd\ne" | awk -v c=1 '{a[NR]=$0} /(b|d)/{hits[NR]} END{ for (hit in hits) { if (x++) print "---"; for (i=hit-c;i<=hit+c;i++) print i (i==hit?":":"-") a[i] } }'
1-a
2:b
3-c
---
3-c
4:d
5-e
```

Obviously that's kinda lengthy to type every time you want to do this but you can use it in a shell script, e.g.:

```
$ cat markRanges
awk -v c="$1" -v re="$2" '
{ a[NR]=$0 }
$0 ~ re { hits[NR] }
END {
    for (hit in hits) {
        if (x++) {
            print "---"
        }
        for (i=hit-c; i<=hit+c; i++) {
            print i (i==hit?":":"-") a[i]
        }
    }
}
'

$ echo -e "a\nb\nc\nd\ne" | ./markRanges 1 '(b|d)'
1-a
2:b
3-c
---
3-c
4:d
5-e
```

Massage to suit...